# Hide keyboard when a user interacts with date picker

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, uidatepicker

I have a text field and a date picker. I want to enter text into the uitextview but once the user interacts with the datepicker I want to hide the keyboard. I've done 3 things:

1) Add a tap gesture recognizer to the rootcontroller's view object which calls a method running `self.view.endEditing(true)`. This hides the keyboard ONLY when the user interacts with anything outside of the textview and datepicker.

2) I've tried creating an IBAction for touch down and then running `self.view.endEditing(true)`. This doesn't work.

3) I've also tried adding a tap gesture recognizer to the date picker but it doesn't get called.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if self.datePicker.frame.contains(touch.location(in: view)) {
          self.view.endEditing(true)
        } 
    }
}
```